# Idiom: it was better before

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom for looking back on the "glory days" and saying "it was better back then."

> it was better before

Comment: If a Shakespearean tag will serve your turn, "We have seen the best of our time." --Gloucester in [*King Lear* 1.2](http://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/Lr_FMe/scene/1.2/).

Comment: People speak in reference to a figurative Eden and a time "before the Fall" that "it was Paradise."

Answer (score 3):

***[Those were the days:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/those-were-the-days)***
​

> something you say that means life was better at the time in the past that you are talking about:
>
> - We were young and madly in love. Ah, those were the days!

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

**back in the day**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Back+in+the+Day)

> At a time in the past that is remembered with fondness or nostalgia.

Answer (score 0):

> [***halcyon days***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/halcyon) - People often use the phrase *halcyon days* to refer idyllically to a calmer, more peaceful time in their past.

Comment: Not so sure about "often" using the phrase....

Comment: [Less often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halcyon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalcyon%3B%2Cc0), sure.  Not my writeup.

Answer (score 0):

[**the good old days**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+old+days)  (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved. via TFD)

> A past period of better times. Often used to describe a time that one believes was better, simpler, or more wholesome than the current period. *Ah, those were the good old days. Did you know I was captain of the football team back then? Were the good old days really that good? I think your memory is a bit rosier than reality.*